Является ли допустимым перечисление псевдоклассов в CSS через запятую?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, является ли допустимым перечислять несколько CSS-псевдоклассов внутри одного селектора? То есть, *:hover, active (например).
.btn_copy:hover, active {
     background: #9afff0;
     text-shadow: 0 0 0 2px;
     border: 1px solid orange;
     border-radius: 3px;
}
<button class="btn_copy">Копировать</button>

Я заметил, что данный способ объединения псевдоклассов, в целом, работает (если требуется объединить оформление для нескольких состояний кнопки), но является ли он допустимым? Можно ли его применять повсеместно, где это требуется?
Заранее благодарю.

Нет, у тебя два селектора, первый выбирает тег с классом btn_copy в состоянии hover и второй выбирает (несуществующий) тег active.

Вы можете использовать старый синтаксис (на 10 мая 2024 поддержка браузерами - 96.97%):
.btn_copy:hover,
.btn_copy:active,
.btn_copy:disabled {
}

или использовать современный синтаксис (поддержка браузерами - 96.94%):
.btn_copy:is(:hover, :active, :disabled) {
}

или так (поддержка браузерами - 86.93%):
.btn_copy {
  &:hover,
  &:active,
  &:disabled {
  }
}

Но лучше всего будет использовать постобработку CSS. Таким образом вы пишете код любым способом, лишь бы он был валидным, а постобработчик уже без вас подумает как ваш код оптимизировать.

Нынче ещё nesting в CSS завезли так что можно ещё так: .btn_copy { &:hover, &:active { ... } }

Большое спасибо!

@AlexeyTen дополнил.

Очевидно, что у первого селектора поддержка 100%, а не какие-то 96.97%. Так же все ссылки в ответе ведут куда-то не туда...

@Qwertiy поправил ссылки. Относительно первого селектора, can i use считает, что 96.97, Поэтому даю ссылки. Эмпирически, вы правы, но всегда может найтись какой-то замороченный браузер. )

@AndreiFedorov, у caniuse просто почему-то часть данных не заполнена.

Так делать можно, только указывать класс все равно нужно с точкой
.btn_copy:hover, .active {...}


Простите, если не так сформулировал вопрос. Я имею в виду не повторять классы (.class, .class2), что, в принципе, похоже, а про перечисление в одном классе нескольких состояний (.class:hover, :active, :focus{} ). И правилен ли синтаксис, коим я перечислил их? Спасибо.
